# UTF-8 characters in Eclipse - maybe a Windows copy 'n paste issue

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, copy-paste

I'm trying to internationalise an Android application. I've a set of strings which I've written out in english, and I'm useing Google translate to convert them to the target language.

Then I'm copy and pasteing the translated text Eclipse, however it's displayed incorrectly in Eclipse.
e.g.
I start with the English

> Bearing, as degrees East of true north

which translates to

> De paliers, comme degrés Est du nord vrai

and when I paste it to Eclipse I get

> De paliers, comme degrÃ©s Est du nord vrai

I've checked and the format for the strings file is UTF-8, also I've checked by posting the translation to notepad and I get the correct characters, which leads me to suspect that it's something to do with Eclipse and Windows 7. Anyone got any ideas or a workaround (i.e. will editing the xml file outside of Eclipse (in notepad for example) work?)

Comment: I do not have any problem with your example. Does XML file Properties (in Eclipse) indeed show UTF8? Yes, you can use Notepad, just Refresh your res folder in Eclipse then. But using Google Translate is a very bad idea.

Comment: I agree Re Google Translate but I can't afford to have someone manualy translate the whole app and I figure some approxamation of their own language is better then forceing everyone to use English. and yea the propeties says UTF8, it was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm French and "De paliers, comme degrés Est du nord vrai" makes no sense at all. It's not "some approximation", it's just that I don't have any clue about what it can mean!! So I'm not sure it's better to have this kind of translation than only English version...

Comment: You can test if it's the clipboard or the editor. In the control panel, add a new keyboard language for French and select the keyboard type as "US-International". Then you will see a EN/FR symbol on the lower right side of your desktop. Select FR and then type the apostrophe followed by e. If it displays an é, then it may be your web browser messing up the copied text.

Comment: @huelbois Thanks! you have a point, I've used Google translate to translate forgen language newspapers to english, and it's been.. OK maybe the shorness of the text is an issue, I'll look into a better option (I have friends who's first language isn't english so maybe I'll ask/enlist/con them into doing some of the major languages)

Comment: @BitBank Thanks,  I'll look into that, I'm away from the workstation running Eclipse at the mo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is UTF-8 (the symbol Ã denotes it) but Eclipse is interpreting your file as probably Cp1252. Right click on the file and check the content encoding Eclipse is using (generally, if not modified, inherited from container which usually defaults to Cp1252. Container is project/Workspace/whole Eclipse settings in that order). Some files however, such as XML are treated according to their content (XML has a header showing the encoding used).

**Update**

If you check that the file is actually being interpreted as UTF-8 by Eclipse then this means a double conversion. When using [Cp-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) Ã has a binary code 0xC3 and © has a binary code 0xA9. If you peek the [UTF-8 charset table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) you will discover that é character has a two byte encoding of 0xC3 0xA9. Sometimes when interpreting data some conversions are automatically made (i.e. when outputting java Strings to other since they originally are always UTF-16) if origin-destination encodings are known. The problem arises when one of the encodings is unknown (your case) and the transformer has to decide (normally using default system encoding). This is when things start getting messed up.

You may end up with Ã© in UTF-8 if original source was indeed in UTF-8 but was interpreted as Cp1252. Original 0xC3 0xA9 (Ã© in Cp1252 or é in UTF-8) sequence is translated to 0xC3 0x83 (Ã in UTF-8) and 0xC2 0xC9 (© in UTF-8).

How can origin encoding being detected if not specified? Normally you can't. That's why most UTF-8 encoders make this double conversion if you feed them back (from Cp1252 to UTF-8 and again to UTF-8 when feeding with the previous output but interpreting the input as Cp1252), unless you are using some mark in the document to tell the encoder about the encoding (such as [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1), which is by the way not supported by Eclipse).

Comment: No sorry the string I want is "De paliers, comme degrés Est du nord vrai" but it's being displayed as "De paliers, comme degrÃ©s Est du nord vrai" But I'll check the file header BRB

Comment: Nope the header is UTF8 as are the file propaties

Comment: Then check that the file is actually being interpreted by Eclipse as UTF-8. So right click on the file and look for "Text File Encoding" part of the "Resource" option of the popup window. You shoud see "Default (determined from content type: UTF-8)" as the checked option.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to General -> Workspace and set Text file encoding to UTF-8. Additionally, if you work on a remote Linux server, set "New text file line delimiter" to Unix.